# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I execute the program, it shows the error: *No value specified for parameter 1*

The error occurs in this statement: 'rowSet.execute();'

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    // Create a RowSet Instance
    RowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl();

    // Establish the Databse Connection
    rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jmysql?autoReconnect=false&useSSL=false");
    rowSet.setUsername("root");
    rowSet.setPassword("root!@#$Mysql2016");
    rowSet.setCommand("SELECT userpassword FROM user WHERE userid = ? "
            + " AND userName = ? ");
    //Execute the Sql Command
    rowSet.execute(); 

    rowSet.setInt("userid", 415);
    rowSet.setString("UserName", "anjeetSharma415@gmail.com");

     // Display the UserPassword
    System.out.print("Password : " + rowSet.getString(3));

    // Close the Connetion
    rowSet.close();
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified
>   for parameter 1   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2611)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2586)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2510)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2259)
>     at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.execute(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:567)   at
>   com.advjdbc.database.chapter.RowSetPerParepedStatement.main(RowSetPerParepedStatement.java:30)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting the exception is that you are calling the `execute()` method before setting all the parameters. 
So you have to set the params as follows (before the execute() method):

```
rowSet.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jmysql?autoReconnect=false& useSSL=false");
rowSet.setUsername("root");
rowSet.setPassword("root!@#$Mysql2016");
rowSet.setCommand("SELECT userpassword FROM user WHERE userid = ? AND userName = ? ");

// set the param values
rowSet.setInt(1, 415);
rowSet.setString(2, "anjeetSharma415@gmail.com");

//Execute the Sql Command
rowSet.execute();
```